# Pass variable from a vbscript to batch file

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

Say I have a batch file where in I call a VBScript(which returns the ERRORLEVEL) like:

```
    @echo off
    echo Passing the control to VBSCript.
    Cscript test.vbs
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    echo done here!!!!
    EXIT /B 0
    )
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1
    echo EROOR!!!!!!!
    EXIT /B 1
    )
```

and the test.vbs is like:

```
    Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
    strComputer = "."
    strKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
    strEntry1a = "DisplayName"
    strEntry1b = "QuietDisplayName"
    strEntry1c = "DisplayVersion"
    .......................................
    ..........some code here...............
    .......................................
    IF i=0 THEN
    WScript.Echo "Congratulations!! Everything is fine......
    WScript.Quit 0
    ELSE
    WScript.Echo "Sorry Mate.. Things out here look bad....
    WScript.Quit 1
    END IF
```

My question is that upon execution of this batch file........ I am not able to catch the %ERRORLEVEL% generated by my VBScript in my batch script(PS: test.vbs is executing fine when ran individually). Moreover , its a weird output I am getting:

```
    Passing the control to VBSCript.
    Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.7
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    ............................
    ............................
    ......VB Code Running........
    ..........here.............

    0 was unexpected at this time.
```

why am I getting "0 was unexpected at this time." error in  Batch file.
How else can I pass Error code from a vbscript to its parent batch script??

Any help is welcome.......
Thanks in advance.

---

### New Edit ,

Thanks PA for your reply..
Actually now I am setting a different variable namely, ERRORLEV as shown below:

```
      IF ERRORLEVEL 0 SET /a ERRORLEV=0
      IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET /a ERRORLEV=1
      IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET /a ERRORLEV=2
      echo the value of ERRORLEV is :
      echo %ERRORLEV%
      if %ERRORLEV% EQU 0 (
      echo Nothing is to be Done
      EXIT /B 0
      )
      IF %ERRORLEV% EQU 2 (
      echo Let start then.......
      EXIT /B 1
      )
```

The best part is now event the variable ERRORLEV is getting set/echoed correctly.
However I am not able to use it in 'IF' command..
I am getting a output of :

```
      the value of ERRORLEV is :
      2
      0 was unexpected at this time.
```

Can you suggest , what might be the case???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in `HELP IF`

*ERRORLEVEL number - Specifies a true condition if the last program run
returned an exit code **equal to or greater than** the number
specified.*

so you need to test ERRORLEVEL with this special syntax.

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 DOTHIS &goto :eof
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 DOTHAT &goto :eof
DOGOOD
```

Comment: Thanks..PA I did it your way.. and its working.....but I am still confused as to why was it not working through the approach mentioned in New Edit?? Any suggestions??.....

Comment: you need to reverse the order of checking, because `IF ERRORLEVEL` checks if the code is equal **or greater**